# Most General Unifier and Result

Tags: prolog

I'm in the process of learning Prolog and am struggling with identifying the Most General Unifier as well as working through the following resolution step to get the new list of goal terms that results from this. An example of what I am working through is below. What is the correct way of going about understanding what is happening here?

```
resolution([append([],B,B)], [append(X,Y, [1,2])]
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at teh Wikipedia [Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) entry? (Actually I should read it myself)

Comment: I have not, I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC MGU is a substitution of variables that make two terms identical.

Since terms are recursive data structures, an intuitive algorithm for [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#A_unification_algorithm) could use a [stack of pairs](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/unify.h) to visit the terms *while* binding variables.

In your example, resolution take 2 lists, so start pushing them together in the stack. Now iterate, pop the top term pair and apply the [basic steps](https://github.com/CapelliC/IL/blob/master/unify.cpp) until the stack become empty - and then unification succeeded - or it cannot - and then fail.

The key observation is that there *must* be identity between *every* pair of elements in the stack. Of course, logical variables play a fundamental role in the game...

Comment: Just to be more specific: the MGU is the *most general* substitution.
An MGU for `foo(B,Y) = foo(A,5)` would be `{B/A, Y/5}'. But a substitution like `{B/3, A/3, Y/5}` would also make the two terms identical. It just would be less general than the MGU.